# Troubles with global messages in Magento

Tags: php, magento, message

My knoledges in magento not so deep so I had a trouble with the magento global messages output.

I created my module. On the index page of my module (the route is /vouchers) I had a form. So by POST i send data to Controller (the route is the same (/voucehrs)) where I validate data:

```
if(!isset($post["to_name"]) || !$post['to_name'])
   {
       Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($this->__('Please enter  "To Name" information'));
       $errors = 1;
   }

...

  if(!$errors)
     {
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Your order is successfully saved and now is in process'));
     }
```

In the template I use     `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` but nothing happens, though I dumped Session variable where I can see success message.

Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Please check your controller. If you renders the layout, you must include the following code in your action.

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
```

So your action should be like this :

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->renderLayout();
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Notice
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Notice message');
```

[image]

```
Success
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success message');
```

[image]

```
Error
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error message');
```

[image]

```
Warning (admin only)
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addWarning('Warning message');
```

[image]

**Output errors from a controller**

```
public function sendAction()
    {
        try
        {
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->send();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error sending mail');
        }
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

[MOre info for session in mageno how to get and set](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/utilizing-magento-notification-system/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `core/session` instead of `customer/session`? It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, we strongly advise you to install/configure Xdebug - this tool will save you lots of time.

As for the issue, try to use

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
```

instead of

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
```

If it doesn't work, you may try:

```
// after post form
$this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->getMessages(true));

// when display
$this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```

Hope it will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this stack overflow post extremely helpful.

What worked for me was a combination of Alex Ivanov's and Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd's answsers, as below (controller code):

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
$this->renderLayout();
```